# Where in this code is my file being converted from 10-bit to 8-bit?

Tags: ffmpeg

I would like my video file to retain 10-bit depth. When I use the code below in ffmpeg, my video is being converted from 10-bit to 8-bit. Any help would be appreciated!

```
ffmpeg -ss 01:42:22 -i "F:\00_Movie_Shot_Fisheye_Template\00_Original_Movie\Blade Runner 2049 (2017)\Blade Runner 2049 (2017).mkv" -to 1:50:00 -vf zscale=t=linear:npl=100,format=gbrpf32le,zscale=p=bt709,tonemap=tonemap=hable:desat=0,zscale=t=bt709:m=bt709:r=tv,format=yuv420p -c:v libx264 -crf 1 -r:v 23.976 -c:a copy -preset ultrafast -tune fastdecode -max_muxing_queue_size 1024 "F:\00_Movie_Shot_Fisheye_Template\02_Original_Image_Sequence\name_of_project-lossless_sequence.mkv"
```

Comment: Way above my "pay grade" so to speak, but I see zscale linear and tonemap and, if I am not mistaken, "tonemap" is often part of the process for converting "HDR" to SDR. I think zscale=t=linear transfers to RGB but I don't know if that has any real impact on 10-bit (gbrpf32le is floating point, and RGB does support e.g. 16-bpp  both FP and Int).

Answer (score 1):

The `format=yuv420p` is the filter that converts to 8-bit. Switch to `yuv420p10le`.